# How to generate random ASCII characters (or hex bytes) 0-255 in PostScript

Tags: postscript

I am trying to generate a random string of hexadecimal bytes in PostScript. I can generate (pseudo-)random integers easily enough:

```
rand 255 mod
```

And perhaps the question is better put this way: Is there a way to convert an integer into an ASCII character? Or a hexadecimal byte?

I have tried so many things, but this language is utter madness.

Comment: "...but this language is utter madness.": Actually PostScript as a language for describing print output is very well designed and has great power. Have you ever tried to get the same font appearance on two different printers using PCL (just for example)?

Answer (score 4):

There are no such things as 'ASCII characters' in PostScript (outside of an ASCII85 encoded data source) and the number you have generated is already a 'hexadecimal byte' in that its an 8-bit integer value.

There are no data objects in the language which correspond to what you seem to be looking for (ASCII character or hecadecmial byte). But you haven't really said what your goal is, if we knew more about the intended final use of the numbers it would be much easier to offer advice.

I'm going to assume that since you want to 'generate a random string of hexadecimal bytes' you actually want a string. So the first thing you need to do is create a string large enough to hold your output. You don't say how large your expected output is, so lets assume you want a 20 byte string.

```
20 string
```

will create you a string which is 20 bytes in length. You then want to generate and store 20 bytes of data. The easiest way to do that, of course, is in a loop. So something like:

```
0 1 19 {
  pop        % remove the loop count from the stack
  rand       % generate a number in the range 0->2^31 -1
  255 mod    % modulo down to the range 0->255
} for
```

You then want to put these bytes into the string, to do that you use the `put` operator. This is defined on page 635 of the 3rd edition PostScript Language Reference Manual. There are three variants depending on the type of the compound object parameter; array, dictionary or string, you obviously want the string version. This takes three arguments; the string, the index into the string where you want the value put, and the value to put at that position.

Its trivial to use the index which we popped from the stack in the loop above as the index into the string. So all that's left is to assemble our procedure:

```
20 string        % Create a string to hold our output
0 1 19           % initial value, increment, and limit, for the loop
{                % stack - string, index
    1 index      % copy the string, stack - string, index, string
    exch         % swap top two stack elements stack - string string index
    rand         % geenrate random number stack - string string index rnd
    255 mod      % bring into range stack - string string index rnd
    put          % put 'rnd' into 'string' at position 'index' stack - string
} for            % end procedure
                 %
                 % stack now contains string with 20 random bytes 0->255
```

If its more convenient you could use an array instead of a string, the technique is exactly the same.

PostScript is actually a very simple language, but its unusual these days in that it is stack based. It does have some subtleties; the use of the string in the program above demonstrates how references to composite objects are effectively treated as pointers, if you actually do want to make a copy of a composite object you need to use the copy operator.

I'm also curious about why you are using the language at all, if you are having so much trouble with it ?